# Koalas applymap moving all data to a single partition

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-koalas

I need to do element-wise operation on a Koalas DataFrame. I use for that the Koalas [applymap](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/databricks.koalas.DataFrame.applymap.html#databricks.koalas.DataFrame.applymap) method. On the execution Koalas moves all data to one partition and then applies the operation. The outcome is that the performance of the job is very poor.

```
>>> sdf = spark.range(0, 10**7, 1, 10).toDF('col1').withColumn('col2', F.lit('[1,2]'))

>>> kdf = ks.DataFrame(sdf)

>>> kdf_new = kdf[['col2']].applymap(eval)

WARN window.WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
```

How to force Koalas not to shuffle data and apply the operation in existing partitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by specifying an index on the Koalas DataFrame. The default index is expected to give poor performance. Read about [default index type](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/options.html#default-index-type) in Koalas.

Either specify a different default index

```
ks.options.compute.default_index_type = 'distributed-sequence'
```

or specify a specific index (i.e. don't use default) on your DataFrame

```
kdf = kdf.set_index('col1')
```